# Passing data onto another activity

Tags: android-intent

-Hello experts,

I have three activities say ActivityOne, ActivityTwo and ActivityThree.

On ActivityOne I have EditText1, EditText2 and Button1. When I click Button1 it should save the data I entered into EditText1 and EditText2 (Sharedpreferences).

I have many data to be stored. I mean once I give 'abc' as the EditText1 and '123' as the EditText2 values and when I click Button1 data should be saved and the next time when I click the Button1 it should save EditText1 and  EditText2 separately and shouldn't overwrite the first one.

On ActivityTwo I have another button called ButtonShow. When I click ButtonShow it should show the list of items I have saved from  ActivityOne and when I select an item from that list it should open ActivityThree with the values against the selected item.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `ActivityOne`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putString("item", "value").commit();
```

In `ActivityThree`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
myName = prefs.getString("buffer", null);
```

Comment: Sorry, because I am not at an expert I couldn't make it work. Can you provide complete code please.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively read about the documentation.
The training section will guide you through examples on how to achieve what you're trying to do, especially this [Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent).
After that you will be able to put data into a Bundle and pass it to the next Activity.

On the first Activity:

```
public void sendMessage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "some data");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And on the second Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
}
```